# Setting IIS 8 Application Pool to Restart Periodically, NOT Recycle

Tags: iis, restart

I'm hoping someone can answer my question because I've read the IIS.net article on this and I'm still confused.  Basically, I want to set my website's application pool to restart every night at midnight.  I've already set it to recycle periodically and that doesn't seem to fix the problem I intended it to fix...restarting manually does, however, and I would like it to restart every night.

I have gone to the IIS 8 Configuration Editor and I'm looking at the periodicRestart variable, but I don't know what values I'm supposed to put in the "schedule" or "time" fields.  They have values of "(Count=0)" and "1.05:00:00", respectively, but I don't know what these are signifying or if they will even have the desired effect if I do, indeed, change them.

Please help, and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a .bat file and run as a scheduled task

```
iisreset [servername]
```